# Как открыть две формы одновременно?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как одним методом открыть две формы одновременно?

Comment: `void ShowDoubleForm() {form1.Show(); form2.Show()}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Достаточно создать обе формы и открыть их:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    Form3 f3 = new Form3();
    f2.Show();
    f3.Show();
}
```